# LineageOS Gerrit push failed: too many commits & forge committer not permitted

Tags: android-source, gerrit

I am setting up a Gerrit LineageOS(fork of AOSP) server locally, but upon my push to gerrit, many of the refs are rejected, giving me the error(s): `prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted` and `too many commits`. I understand the too many commits message, but even when checking the `--skip-validation` option, I was given the same forge committer message.

This is a linux server running Ubuntu, with Gerrit 2.15. I tried the skip option as stated above, and also did enable forge committing in the gerrit `all-projects` permissions.

The commands I used were(this worked fine): 
`repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PATH; ssh -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit create-project --name blinkOS/$REPO_PATH --owner blinkOS --parent blinkOS;'` 
to create branches, and this one to push(error ridden per push): 
`repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PATH; git push ssh://admin@localhost:29418/blinkOS/$REPO_PATH +refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*;'` The create command worked(parent project name is blinkOS), the push one is giving me the errors.

Expectedly, it should push, but it does not push all files, only some, and rejects the majority.

Here is a snippet of some of the error messages(i just took the most recent ones):

```
 ! [remote rejected]   studio-2.3 -> studio-2.3 (prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted)
 ! [remote rejected]   studio-3.0 -> studio-3.0 (prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted)
 ! [remote rejected]   studio-3.1.2 -> studio-3.1.2 (prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted)
 ! [remote rejected]   studio-master-dev_before_26911779 -> studio-master-dev_before_26911779 (prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted)
 ! [remote rejected]   studio-master-dev_before_27917934 -> studio-master-dev_before_27917934 (prohibited by Gerrit: forge committer not permitted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some thorough searhing, and soon after, realized I had the correct permissions pushed to `refs/heads/*`, but not to `refs/tags/*`, I then added the forge committer identity and all forge permissions to the `refs/tags/*` branch and it ended up allowing me to push and create a branch.